# Layered Navigation for Custom Product Collection filtered via Custom Attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, layered-navigation, layer

I have a filtered product collection using custom attribute. How do I implement layered navigation for the same?

I have extended **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List** in my block to and override *_getProductCollection()* to update **$this->_productCollection** variable filtering it through a custom attribute. It gets nicely displayed.

But the layered navigation section appears to be unchanged. It appears to show all products. I want to show only **$this->_productCollection** products in layered navigation.

How do I do it? I feel that I may have to extend *Mage_Catalog__Model_Layer* and I even tried to but I couldn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Do you want to get filtered collection, based on custom attributes?

Comment: I want to get my layered navigation to work properly. My custom attribute filtered productCollection has no problom. Just tell me how to get layered navigation menu according to this new ProductCollection.

Comment: I've been cracking my head over this as well. The only post I found that makes a bit more sense and might help you in the right direction is this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726891/magento-layered-navigation-on-custom-product-collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726891/magento-layered-navigation-on-custom-product-collection) Only problem I have is that I can't get it working. I extended Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer and updated getProductCollection with the same adjustments made in list.php. This works but since it's a model it works for the entire webshop while I only want